# OpenCV: issues with playing videos created using ffmpeg and concat

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg

I concatenated a few videos using:

```
$ ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list_files.txt -c copy total.mp4
```

where `list_files.txt` is like:

```
file 'file1.mp4'
file 'file2.mp4'
```

Unfortunately, if I play it with opencv:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Create a VideoCapture object and read from input file
# If the input is the camera, pass 0 instead of the video file name
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('../Video_outputs/010_introduction.mp4')

# Check if camera opened successfully
if (cap.isOpened()== False): 
  print("Error opening video stream or file")

# Read until video is completed
while(cap.isOpened()):
  # Capture frame-by-frame
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  if ret == True:

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)

    # Press Q on keyboard to  exit
    if cv2.waitKey(24) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break

  # Break the loop
  else: 
    break

# When everything done, release the video capture object
cap.release()

# Closes all the frames
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the first video plays fine, but the next concatenated videos are ugly looking:

[image]

Am I missing something, or is it a bug to report upstream?

PS: I'm using this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Create a VideoCapture object and read from input file
# If the input is the camera, pass 0 instead of the video file name
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('../Video_outputs/010_introduction.mp4')

# Check if camera opened successfully
if (cap.isOpened()== False): 
  print("Error opening video stream or file")

# Read until video is completed
while(cap.isOpened()):
  # Capture frame-by-frame
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  if ret == True:

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)

    # Press Q on keyboard to  exit
    if cv2.waitKey(24) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break

  # Break the loop
  else: 
    break

# When everything done, release the video capture object
cap.release()

# Closes all the frames
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: play that video with ffplay or VLC. what does it look like then?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz it works fine. If I re-encode the video, it works with opencl, but it's a bit annoying to do.

Comment: can you provide a sample video file that exhibits the behavior? (also the individual video pieces to replicate)

Comment: What happens if you read the video frame with ffmpeg in Python rather than opencv? (e.g., via a ffmpeg subprocess call, `ffmpegio` or `ffmpeg-pyton`?)

Comment: The fact that videos are MP4, created using FFmpeg and concat, is not enough information... Please use [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo), or FFprobe to give us the codec information, the pixel format and other parameters. You are also not telling us if the second video plays fine before the concat. Note: When using concat demuxer all media files should be with exactly the same codec and codec parameters - verify they are the same. After all that, I think we really need a video sample...

Comment: Thanks all, I'll provide a sample soon.